# SSLConfigFactory parse NoSuchMethodError

Tags: websocket, akka

I'm playing with Akka HTTP websocket with java, I was trying to implement the server side with the example from https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.0.1/docs/src/test/java/docs/http/javadsl/server/WebSocketCoreExample.java, but I have come up with an exception when I ran the application.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.sslconfig.ssl.SSLConfigFactory$.parse(Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;)Lcom/typesafe/sslconfig/ssl/SSLConfigSettings;
>       at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.defaultSSLConfigSettings(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:34)
>       at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.createExtension(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:29)
>       at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.createExtension(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:19)
>       at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:746)
>       at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:79)
>       at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.apply(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:24)
>       at com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.AkkaSSLConfig$.apply(AkkaSSLConfig.scala:19)
>       at akka.http.scaladsl.HttpExt.(Http.scala:47)
>       at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.createExtension(Http.scala:813)
>       at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.createExtension(Http.scala:689)
>       at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:746)
>       at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:79)
>       at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.apply(Http.scala:808)
>       at akka.http.scaladsl.Http$.apply(Http.scala:689)
>       at akka.http.javadsl.Http.delegate$lzycompute(Http.scala:45)
>       at akka.http.javadsl.Http.delegate(Http.scala:45)
>       at akka.http.javadsl.Http.defaultServerHttpContext(Http.scala:682)
>       at akka.http.javadsl.Http.bindAndHandleSync(Http.scala:220)
>       at com.tr.ap.endpoint.WebSocketServer.startUp(WebSocketServer.java:58)
>       at com.tr.ap.endpoint.WebSocketServer.main(WebSocketServer.java:50)

Can anyone help me with the issue, thank you.

Comment: You seem to combine incompatible akka-http / akka / ssl-config versions. If you use sbt can you post the output of `show externalDependencyClasspath`?

Comment: I'm using maven, below is my configuration in pom.xml:
<artifactId>akka-http-core_2.11</artifactId>
<version>10.0.0</version>

<artifactId>akka-http_2.11</artifactId>
<version>10.0.0</version>

<artifactId>ssl-config-core_2.12.0-M3</artifactId>
<version>0.1.2</version>

Comment: When I change ssl-config-core version to 2.11, then the exception turns to be java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.sslconfig.util.LoggerFactory